# App store Version number and build number

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, ipa

I had an app on app store with version 1.1.1 and build 85

While doing an update of the app using application loader the app I used version 1.2.0 and build 5.

It says that build version has to be higher than 85.

Is it that build number should always be incremental irrespective of version number.

If the version number is incremented as in our case can't we use a lower build number

Please point to some apple documentation on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which iOS app version/build number(s) MUST be incremented upon App Store release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125159/which-ios-app-version-build-numbers-must-be-incremented-upon-app-store-release)

Answer (score 3):

Both build version numbers need to increment. They can be different numbers and different formats, but they both have to go up with each successive version you want to submit.

Comment: By both build version you mean -  the version and the build number ?

Comment: As in `CFBundleVersion` and `CFBundleShortVersionString`

Answer (score 2):

For each version number, e.g. (version 1), the build number will need to be incremented.
So the following is acceptable

- Version 1; build 1
- Version 1; build 2
- Version 1; build 3
- Version 1; build 4

... now, when you come to increase your version number, to say (version 2), you will be able to reset the build number back to say 1, if you want.

- Version 2; build 1
- Version 2; build 2
- Version 2; build 3
- Version 2; build 4

Just note that each new build number must be greater than the previous one.

Hope this helps someone else :-)

Answer (score 0):

i had versioning problem for hotfix so I tested few cases. 
and it can give you little more information, i think.

1.5.10(150) > 1.5.11(1) Failed. 
xcode uploader said upload version should have larger number than 150. maybe my version has 2 period seperated version style.

1.5.10(150) > 1.5.11(180) obviously

1.5.11(180) > 1.5.11(1.5.11.1) Failed

1.5.11(160) > 1.5.11(160.1) has no problem.